# Do Egyptians need visa for Northern Cyprus (TRNC) or Turkey?

Tags: visas, paperwork, turkey, egyptian-citizens, northern-cyprus

I am Egyptian and I hold a BRP residence permit in the UK. I want to travel to the Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus. Do I need a visa for both Turkey and TRNC?

Answer (score 2):

For the TRNC, you don't need a visa for up to 90 days.

For Turkey: as in most places, you need no documentation other than an onward ticket if **not** leaving the airport's transit area.

If you need to leave the transit area, however (for example if you're on separate bookings with luggage to pick up and re-check), you need to buy either:

1. An [e-visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/apply/) to be presented with your passport and BRP card at Turkish border control.
2. A regular visa at the airport visa desk, for which you need both your passport and BRP card

Answer (score 1):

Northern Cyprus has very relaxed visa regulations. For visits for up to 90 days, only citizens of Nigeria and Armenia need to apply for a visa prior to traveling.

Source: [Website of MFA of TRNC](http://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/)

So, no, you don't need a visa. But keep in mind that,

> Foreigners are required to have the following in their possessions at
>   the port of entry to the TRNC:
>
> - A valid passport
> - £85 (Sterling Pounds) or equivalent per day the visitor intends to stay
> - Round trip ticket
> - Proof of confirmed hotel reservation
> - For visiting family or friends, a letter of invitation which provides name, address, phone number and other contact information in
>     full
> - If traveling for higher education, an official acceptance letter from the university
> - If traveling on a business trip, an official letter of invitation from a company in the TRNC

Comment: The one catch is that there's no direct flights to TRNC: you need to transit either via Turkey or the Republic of Cyprus, and may need visas to do so.

Comment: @jpatokal Not for TUrkey if staying in the transit area, and even if leaving it, she just needs an e-visa